# Что значит двойное двоеточие (::) в Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-faq

```
val gson = Gson().fromJson(reader, JsonObject::class.java).asJsonObject
```

На примере кода выше, что такое `::` в записи `JsonObject::class.java`

Comment: Похоже на ссылку на метод

Comment: Это, кстати, и в Java есть. Называется [Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). Появилось в Java 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JsonObject::class.java
```

Это ссылка на Java класс

В Общем случае оператор `::` является ссылкой на метод или класс

Если вам нужна ссылка на Kotlin класс, то достаточно `ClassName::class` если же вам нужна ссылка на Java класс, то в конце необходимо добавить `.java`

Подробнее почитайте в [документации с примерами](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references)